# Simply move row to another table and back

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an easy way to SELECT a row and INSERT it into another table that has exactly the same columns? It needs to reserve the id and be able to move it back later on.

STEPS:

1. Move entire row to an identical temporary table (with a different name of-course) while using the same id.
2. Delete the row from old table (I know this, dont worry ;))
3. Move the row back from the temporary table into the original table, while using the same original id.
4. Delete row from temporary table.

I know how to do this, but there are probably much better, cleaner and faster ways to achieve this in one or two queries. My main concern is that when the table gets refactored, the query should still do its job without skipping newer columns.

I hope someone can come with a good suggestion :)

Comment: or just skip steps 1,2,3,4 and you have the same thing. :) JK. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you want to copy a row to a duplicate table?  Why not copy all rows and delete as necessary - I assume you are doing some sort of filtering.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why someone would want this. Sometimes you just want to reserve a piece of information without updating a column 'reserved' = 1 or 0.

Comment: @Lobo: Well, it's not necessarily the same thing, since the DELETE may update or delete rows referencing the row via foreign keys defined as e.g "`ON UPDATE CASCADE`" or "`ON DELETE SET NULL`", as well as fire any BEFORE and AFTER statement level and row level triggers.

Comment: @spencer7593 I get it. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the tables have identical columns, you should be able to just do this:

```
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable WHERE id = somevalue
```

Comment: How does it take care of adding new columns to oldtable?

Comment: @GillianLoWong It's standard protocol here to accept an answer that solves the problem ;)

Comment: @Lobo ...add a second line and switch newtable and oldtable in it? How is that not the most obvious thing ever?

Comment: @GillianLoWong Right, I forgot there was a time restriction; thought you'd just forgotten. Never mind then! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @DiMono `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` will not create table/columns. It can only be used to copy data not schema. If you add a column to oldtable and then run this query, the new column value will be lost and if it is `NOT NULL` the second `INSERT INTO` copying data back to oldTable will fail.

Comment: OP said the tables were identical. And in my answer I said "Assuming the tables have identical columns". So while you're correct, the thing you're addressing isn't necessary.

Comment: You are right if the tables are always identical. OP also says "My main concern is that when **the table** gets refactored, the query should still do its job without skipping newer columns." I was just making sure OP knows what he is doing. Good answer btw.

Answer (score 1):

You use [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html) to create a table and then work with it. This will create a table with columns from `SELECT` in your case the original table. Then you can delete the rows from original table, move the rows back to the original table using [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) followed by  dropping the temporary table. This way you don't need to maintain two tables and the temporary table will always get the latest columns from the original table.

See mysql [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html). Following example copied from manual.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+---+
| n |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

mysql> CREATE TABLE bar (m INT) SELECT n FROM foo;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM bar;
+------+---+
| m    | n |
+------+---+
| NULL | 1 |
+------+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So you need something like this

```
CREATE TABLE bar SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooColumn = 'whatever';
DELETE FROM foo where fooColumn <> 'whatever';
INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM bar;
DROP TABLE bar
```

if you want to avoid creating and dropping tables too often, just create the temporary table once.

```
INSERT INTO bar SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooColumn = 'whatever';
DELETE FROM foo where fooColumn <> 'whatever';
INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM bar;
```

But make sure you keep the temporary and the original table in sync all the time i.e. if you add or drop a column in the original table, make sure that is replicated in the temporary table immediately as `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` only copies data not schema.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One thing I forgot to mention was that the script will be moving rows 'randomly' throughout the day. So I cant have the table be dropped and re-created. The two tables will stay identical. Nevertheless your answer will come in handy in the future :)

Comment: sounds reasonable. Is you are going `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` way, make sure you have your temporary table schema in sync with the original table otherwise, it will skip all new columns conveniently.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two alternate ideas I can think of:

1. Add a BIT or BOOL column to the table that can be updated in order to 'flag' the record one way or another so that you can filter on it in your queries.
2. Create a table that just lists the ID of the record(s) that you want to flag. Enter a new ID into this field when you want it flagged (replaces the act of deleting and moving to the 2nd table) and remove it when you wish to 'unflag' it (replaces the act of deleting it from the 2nd table and re-adding it to the original table.

Aside from the initial schema change required by option 1, both options will work regardless of any changes to the schema of the original table. If you are trying to avoid maintaining the second table, I'd consider these.

If you do wish to copy to the holding table and delete from the original table, and later copy back to the original table, and delete from the holding table, be sure to wrap those operations into a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) so that you don't end up with duplicated data or data loss in the event of things not going as planned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
INSERT INTO tbltemp (Select * from table1 where someid=somevalue)
```

Or you could move the entire table into other one :

```
INSERT INTO tbltemp (select * from table1);
```

What ever you do, be careful that the record/records which you need to move/copy must not include any primary key values which are already there in target table.